# Integration by first principle?

Tags: integration

Is there a "formal" counterpart (or equivalent) to the process of differentiation by first principle for computing integral?

Comment: I would be quite surprised if the primitive is elementary, since WolframAlpha isn't even trying.

Comment: Maybe you want to know $\int_0^\infty \sin x/(x^3+\sqrt{x}) dx$? There is better chance for an explicit expression for the definite integral.

Comment: By letting $x=t^2$ and applying PFD over complex numbers, you'll get integrals of the form $\int\frac{\sin(t^2)}{t-a}\ dt$.  From there, replace sine with its complex exponential definition and use incomplete gamma functions.

Comment: @simplybeautifulart what is PFD in this context?

Comment: @unseen_rider Partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: user12345 Do not change your original question here, to one that is very much **unrelated** to this original.